# How to transform an RGB array to simulate colourblindness

Tags: python, math

So far, my code has the array for the image, I'm struggling with how to do the maths in order to transform the image with rgb values that simulate what a **deuteranope** person would see.

```
for x in array:
    for y in x:
        if y[1] > 200:
            y[1] -= 60

        elif 100 < y[1] < 200:
            y[1] -= 30

        elif 15 < y[1]<100:
            y[1] -= 15
```

This decreases the green values a lot but it ends up looking ridiculous.

Comment: Are you searching for a formula or do you have problems to implement a formula you already have? In latter case, add formula to question (or, if necessary, link to it).

Comment: and is there a reference to what a **deuteranope** person would see? if i had to suggest a change though, i'd guess it would be better to just scale the values to a smaller range (say 0 to 150 out of 0 to 255), rather than subtracting hardcoded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a formula that transforms all colors in some way.

I found a [JavaScript library for these transforms here](https://github.com/skratchdot/color-blind/blob/master/lib/blind.js) – it would be a good starting point for porting to Python.

Another option is using lookup tables that transform colors; there are some [here](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind/) with additional reading attached.

Comment: The code is rather long and involved if you ask me (I did actually take a shot at porting it to Python myself, and it didn't exactly work from the get-go, so it's not simple). There are also license issues to consider there; posting the code here would effectively relicense it under SO's terms (CC-BY-SA) from MIT which I do not have the authority to do

Comment: The license issue looks like an excellent reason to me. You get my upvote.